# Playframework Multiple File Upload

Tags: java, file, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am using [JavaFileUpload](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFileUpload) and want to upload multiple pdf files.

HTML part:

```
 @helper.form(action = routes.Application.uploadPost, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
        <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="pdf" accept="application/pdf" multiple autofocus >
        <p>
            <input type="submit">
        </p>
        }
```

I must change `body.getFile("pdf") as`body.getFiles() to be able to get every pdf document that I want to upload successfully. 
I can see every document if I use `getFiles()` and if I use `getFile("pdf")` it just selects first document.

I tried to upload five pdf documents and here is the difference between `getFiles()` and `getFile("pdf")`

```
output of getFiles():  [play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart@3ac08835, play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart@362e6db5, play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart@2224a1dd, play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart@12fec5ae, play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart@14642c40]

output of getFile("pdf"):  play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart@3ac08835
```

in the Java part, if I change `getFile("pdf")` as `getFiles()`, it tells me to add cast. So it offers me two options. One is to add `FilePart` cast, second is to change type of pdf to `List<FilePart>`

If I add `FilePart` cast for `getFiles()` like this `FilePart pdf = (FilePart) body.getFiles();` PlayFramework shows me an exception: `[ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper cannot be cast to play.mvc.Http$MultipartFormData$FilePart]`
 If I change type of pdf to `List<FilePart>`, it then offers me to add a cast to `pdf.getFilename()` like this: `((FilePart) pdf).getFilename()`, also it offers me to add two casts to `File file = pdf.getFiles()` like this: `File file = (File) ((MultipartFormData) pdf).getFiles()`. If I run the code I also get the same exception.

- Is there any way to upload multiple pdf documents in this case?

Half code: ( I can add full code if needed. The rest of code is parsing by using PDFBox and indexing into Solr and HBase

```
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData;
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart;

MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

    for(int i=0; i<body.getFiles().size(); i++) {
    body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart pdf = body.getFile("pdf"); //getFiles();
    String fileName = pdf.getFilename();
    File file = pdf.getFile(); //getFiles(); 
    ...
```

Play framework version: 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the difference between getFiles() and getFile("pdf") is former gets list of files while latter get only one file.

Try the following code.

```
List<FilePart> fileParts = request().body().asMultipartFormData().getFiles();
for(FilePart filePart : fileParts) {
   filePart.getFile();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. `List<FilePart> fileParts = request().body().asMultipartFormData().getFiles();
for(FilePart filePart : fileParts)` These two lines saved my day